# Which is the better Topology? Left or Right? - [With Image Reference]

Tags: mesh, workflow, topology

Which is the better topology for swimsuit?
Left or right.

I am thinking right because legs might move around.
But when i combine the meshes and sub-D them the left one looks better.
What do you guys think?

i started with planes to draw the line of how the V of the shape is made.
And from there i would build inwards. i also already make the center.
But you always get in trouble at some point. xP

Also is it best practice to keep every square same size?
cause sometimes i see people having way longer squares like i have at the edge.

> (Was already answered with it being a choice not a fact)
>   "Entirely depends on what you're doing. It can make certain things easier, like UV mapping (especially if you have to unwrap manually), and animated meshes will deform better (more predictably) if all the polys are the same size, but the renderer shouldn't care."

Its bottom part of swimsuit btw.

Ty so much everyone for all the tips.
I am trying my best to make this edit the best ^^

<3
[image]

Comment: Maybe the question can be reworded to, "What are some of the issues people face with different polygon layouts."  





One answer to this might be another question:  What does the mesh look like when a Sub-D modifier is added to both meshes?  If there is a difference then you have to choose which method looks best to you.

Answer (score 1):

It **entirely** depends on what you're making. Edge-flow is a well-studied science all its own, so there are some good articles out there about how to make those decisions, like [this one](http://www.3dtotal.com/index_tutorial_detailed.php?id=495#.Uv0el_ldU9Y).

That being said, you ask if it's good practice to keep all the polys the same size. That also entirely depends on what you're doing. It can make certain things easier, like UV mapping (especially if you have to unwrap manually), and animated meshes will deform better (more predictably) if all the polys are the same size, but the renderer shouldn't care.

The most important thing you need to do here is merge the center line into one line. Other than that, we need more info about what problems you're facing and what you're trying to accomplish.