# Most ideal way to connect two parts of a mesh when one has multiple faces?

Tags: modeling

I often run into scenarios similar to the following:
[image: 1]

I have two parts that I need to connect together, but one has (a lot) more parts to it. There are two approaches I'd usually do to solve this. Here's one:
[image: 2]

The problem with this method is that everything won't be connected together. I can select any of the vertices (along the widget, x axis) and move them around, and they will move freely. They are not connected. Here's another approach:
[image: 3]

This method connects everything together, but everything looks absurd. It is hard to tell what's what, and everything looks so pinched and hideous.

If I come across a similar scenario (picture 1), how would I approach modeling the two parts together? What would be *considered* the most ideal/best method? Thanks.

Comment: I think that (as many things involving topology) it depends on what is the purpose of the modeling. See possible related (if not duplicated) questions: [What's the best way to topologize this?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/whats-the-best-way-to-topologize-this) or [Which is the better Topology? Left or Right?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/which-is-the-better-topology-left-or-right-with-image-reference).

Comment: Whenever I run into a problem like this, my approach is usually to re-evaluate the geometry of whatever I'm doing. As I'm sure you know, neither of these solutions are particularly great, so I usually have to end up remodeling some aspect of my scene.

Although, as Carlo mentioned, it might not matter if you have a bit of ugly geometry depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When connecting a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh you can progressively reduce the vertices in several steps. This can be helpful if you don't want the extra vertices to continue through the entire mesh.

Here is an all quad sample that takes three steps to go from 22 to 2.

[image]

Comment: Smart! :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be in the lower rectangle in your example Add 22 loop cuts to the same rectangle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> use the Mouse Wheel to add more loop cuts. Left Mouse click when satisfied. Then you can connect the vertices and add faces.

In a more complex shape but still similar to your example you could delete the face in the lower object then select the upper edge press <kbd>W</kbd> and select Subdivide from the drop down menu add 22 new vertices in the Tool Shelf (Pressing the letter <kbd>T</kbd> toggles the window). Repeat this for the lower edge. Then you can connect the vertices and add faces.